# Which one is correct: FAQ page OR the page FAQ

Tags: nouns, adjuncts

In situations that you want to talk/write about a noun that is the name of a specific instance (like `FAQ`) of a common noun (like `page`) which one is correct:

- `common noun` + `specific noun` like *the page FAQ*
- `specific noun` + `common noun` like *the FAQ page*

I have seen both of the above. I know that *FAQ page* (grammatically called **noun adjunct**) is more common but I want to know if both are grammatically correct. What is the first one grammatically called? There are a lot of similar cases like:

- *the site Stackoverflow* vs. *Stackoverflow site*
- *the library Struts* vs. *Struts library*
- *the column Modify Date* vs. *Modify Date column*
- *the button Cancel* vs. *Cancel button*

To clear my gray area, it's worth mentioning that the specific noun is not always a proper noun like the following examples:

- *the word stack* vs. *stack word* (stack is not a proper noun)
- *the compound noun "chicken soup"* vs. *"chicken soup" compound noun* ("chicken soup" here is not considered the name of a food but just a sample of a compound noun so it is a proper noun)

Comment: Note that the use of a  common noun makes it less likely that it would normally come first. If a proper noun is used, it's more of an evenly divided style choice.

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks for suggesting the question. It is insifghtful, but I'm not sure if it covers all cases, e.g. the button Cancel in which Cancel is not a proper noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford in your profile, I think "Editors Canada" and "the software company VMware"  are good examples can be discussed in this question, especially "Editors Canada". *Canadian Editors* sounds more correct to me as a non-native speaker based on what I have learned about English. However, it must be definitely grammatically correct as it is coined by native English writers. What is its grammatical structure?

Comment: The proper name of the organization, at least informally, is *Editors Canada*. That's its actual name, not its description. *Canadian Editors* is wrong, because that's not its name. However, *Canadian editors* is fine, in a different context, because the lowercase *editors* is a common noun. I have no idea what you mean when you are asking about its grammatical structure. What particular component are you referring to?  Are you really just concerned with common nouns versus proper nouns?

Comment: And, from an earlier comment I see of yours, *Cancel* ***is*** a proper noun if you've capitalized it. (Or at least you've signalled that it is by using a capital letter.) If it's not actually a proper noun, then it should be in lowercase.

Comment: By grammatical structure, I mean something like *adjective + noun* or *noun adjunct + noun*. My concern is the *order of nouns* when a *noun* is used as a specific instance of a common noun regardless of that the specific instance is a proper noun (like name of movie/city/etc.) or a common noun. As an example with a common noun, please look at my sample: *the word stack vs. stack word*, both "word" and "stack" are common nouns. If I want to talk about the specific word itself, i.e. "stack" which sentence is correct: *The word stack contains 5 letters* OR *The stack word contains 5 letters*?

Comment: Coming back to *Editors Canada*, since it's a proper noun, maybe asking about the grammatical reason of placing *Editors* before *Canada* isn't a good idea, because a proper noun can be anything. For example, I may call my company "Canada XYZ" or something like that. However, I think *editors Canada* isn't grammatically correct in any context. Is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107746/discussion-between-abdollah-and-jason-bassford).